# Visual Studio Launch Condition

Tags: windows-installer

This may be one of the frequently asked Q. but i haven't come across any help so far. While creating an MSI package for an application, I've a requirement where I need to check if JDK 1.7.0 is installed. If yes, proceed with the installation else, show a message which after the user's permission will redirect to the Install URL to install the prerequisite.

I've used the "Add Registry Search" but the condition I've provided either always fails or always pass. Below are the parameters I've used:

**ADD REGISTRY SEARCH**:

Property: JDKEXISTS

RegKey: SOFTWARE\JAVASOFT\JAVA DEVELOPMENT KIT

Root: vsdrrHKLM

Value: currentversion

**LAUNCH CONDITION:**

Condition: (JDKEXISTS="Installed")

InstallUrl: the url to be downloaded from

Message: Your system needs Java 1.7.0 or higher. Download it now?

However, its not working. Can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

If the registry search finds the item in the registry, then all you need use as a condition is JDKEXISTS. That's enough. I don't know if that value is actually "Installed", which is what you're checking, but you don't need it. JDKEXISTS will not exist (and will be false) if the value isn't found.

That looks like a VS setup project. There is also a bug of sorts in VS setup projects registry search. There's no way to search the native 64-bit registry, in case that is where your key is. The registry search always searches the 32-bit registry. You'd need to edit your MSI file (with Orca) to modify the RegLocator table Type value to add the 64-bit search option (add 16). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371171(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Doesn't work, even tried with "Add File Search" condition and specifying a unique filename to look for under [ProgramFiles64Folder] with a search depth of 3. And simply mentioning 'NOT JDKEXISTS' in the condition section. Apparently, works well if the prerequisite is installed (i.e., skips JDK installation) but it even skips JDK installation if its not installed. I'm guessing 'NOT JDKEXISTS' is not the appropriate condition.

Kinda in a mess here!

Comment: Not sure what you're doing but I can find notepad.exe in [SystemFolder] with a Depth of 0 and a file in [ProgramFiles64Folder] too.  I test by setting the text in the Welcome dialog to.... The [GOTINTEL] installer will guide you thro...  where GOTINTEL is the property name, and it returns the path to the file.  Your search might be working but something further along is not.

Comment: Ok, so now I want to redirect the user to the Install URL in case JDK is not installed. How should I be setting the condition for that?

Comment: Add the condition to the Launch Conditions node together with the error message, and use the property in the condition, such as NOT JDKEXISTS

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but somehow, the condition is screwed up! Maybe 'NOT' is not a proper keyword..

Comment: I'm having a brain fart. The launch condition must evaluate to true for the install to proceed - you just need JDKEXISTS so the install proceeds if you find it with a search.

Comment: Sir, I understand that the condition must evaluate to true but I guess you're not getting the point.. I want the installation to proceed only in case JDK **exists**.. So, if JDK **does not** exist, i.e if NOTJDKEXISTS (condition evaluated to true), prompt for download (Message). I know its a bit confusing, but this is what the requirement is.. But now, in my case, it always prompts for download irrespective of the presence of JDK...

Comment: Do the install with a verbose log - msiexec /I <path to msi> /l*vx <path to log file> to see what's going on in AppSearch and if JDKEXISTS is being set in cases where the item is there or not. Also, I believe I am not confused :) If JDKEXISTS is set because it found the item then the install will proceed as you require because the JDK is there.

Comment: I got tired of it.. no more launch conditions! I did all that checking by writing code... ;) Anyways, thanks for the suggestion! ;)